# change background color of row in Datagrid wpf on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a `DataGrid` and need change the background color of one row.
The `DataGrid` uses scroll and when i try this code, the background also scrolls.

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)gg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);                   
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: For changing things on GUI side, i suggest you to use WPF Data Binding

Answer (score 0):

There is event called "LoadingRow" which called when Row loading to the gridView you can place your condition there, e.g:

```
private void table_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MyData)e.Row.DataContext).Module.Trim().Equals("SomeText"))
        {
            e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```